# Smooth modeling for incomplete tensor by the PARAFAC decomposition - Matlab to Python Conversion

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert the **Matlab** code to **Python3** code: [SPC matlab code](https://github.com/Kaimaoge/Tensor-decomposition-completion-and-recovery-papers-and-codes/blob/master/SPC_software_ver2.3/Function_SPC/SPC.m)

## Code (Matlab which I want to convert to Python)

I am stuck on the following (**highlighted the confusing section**):

```
if strcmp(TV_QV,'tv') 

      u = innerprod_one_exc(E,U,k,n);
      u = u(:);
      %initilization
      a = u/norm(u);
      % main iteration for constrained version
      object = 0.5*G(k)^2*rho(n)*sum(abs(P{n}*a)) - G(k)*a'*u;
      for nn = 1:1000
        df = P{n}'*sign(P{n}*a);
        dL = (0.5*G(k)^2*rho(n)*df - G(k)*u + G(k)^2*a)/G(k)^2;
        al = [0 0.1 0.01 0.001 0.0001 0.00001];
        for ai = 1:length(al)
          a2 = a - al(ai)*dL;
          a2 = a2/norm(a2);
```

> ```
>         score(ai) = 0.5*G(k)^2*rho(n)*sum(abs(P{n}*a2)) - G(k)*a2'*u;
>       end
>       [object2 ai] = min(score);
> ```

```
        a2 = a - al(ai)*dL;
        a2 = a2/norm(a2);
        if abs(object2 - object)/II(n) < 1e-3
          break;
        else
          a = a2;
          object = object2;
        end
      end
      lam = norm(a);
      u = a/lam;
      U{n}(:,k) = u;
      v{n} = u;
      div  = div + rho(n)*sum(abs(P{n}*u));
.... % code continues on
```

## Analysis

From my analysis the RHS of `score(ai) = ...` is a vector, but `score(ai)` would be just a single element in a matrix/array. Thus, after the for-loop, `score` will have 6 vector elements that can vary in length.

## Question

In the following:

```
[object2 ai] = min(score);
```

it seems like `object2` and `ai` will only be float and integer respectively. However, I struggle to understand how this is possible from `min(score)` as `score` has many 6 vector elements of different lengths.

If someone could explain this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is it a minimal example?

Comment: I believe so, the entire code is in the provided link, as it would be impractical to include it all in a code block in the question (in my opinion). I included the section where I am having issues understanding and highlighted/explained what I have troubles with. Anything else I should include which would be of assistance to you?